# Embedding HTML code in extended email Jenkins plugin

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

I am trying to use extended email plugin to send embedded HTML to mail. In section "Editable Email Notification" > "Default Content" I am trying to write some HTML code:

```
<b>Test Result Summary:</b>
</br><iframe width="900" height="400" src="http://jenkins.eng.company.com:8080/view/Nimbus/job/Nimbus_SDDC_Nightly/allure/#/home"></iframe>
</br><b>Feature Wise Test Result:</b>
</br><iframe width="900" height="800" src="http://jenkins.eng.company.com:8080/view/Nimbus/job/Nimbus_SDDC_Nightly/allure/#/features"></iframe>
```

The mail which I am getting is just line 1 and 3 and not the iframe. I want to get these content as well in the mail. How can I achieve this?

Comment: most email clients block iframes. jenkins email plugin may filter them out as well. better just put links not iframes.

Comment: Basically I want to get the content of link, not the link.